# Cutting a string avoiding tags

Tags: php, regex, substr

I'm cutting a string for teasering out of a longer string. Works good.
How can i avoid that if the string contains some HTML-Tags the cut does not happen inside a tag?

```
$input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores <a href="bla.html">Klick.</a> et ea rebum. Stet clita <a href="bla.html">Klick.</a> kasd gubergren, no sea takimata <a href="bla.html">Klick.</a> sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

$last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), '.');
$trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);
```

Comment: can you share your input string and expected output as well?

Comment: the input string is just some text including normal html tags (which are getting cut).

Comment: Maybe [`strip_tags`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is your friend.

Comment: Make en effort, use search. E.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268387/truncate-text-without-truncating-html

Comment: The issue here is that "inside a tag" is not that easily detected since it is not that clearly defined. What _exactly_ do you mean by that?

Comment: well it cuts like until "... takimata <a href="bla.", which is of course not good.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks. haven't found anything. will check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cut html input while preserving tags with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548358/cut-html-input-while-preserving-tags-with-php)

Comment: What if you have something like this: `abc def <p> ghi. jkl </p> mno pqr`?

Comment: Please post **clear** sample of the **input** and desired **output**